# Firebase cloud function: await admin.dbRef.once(‘value’)

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

Using the above method, which has been working perfectly until this morning, I’m suddenly getting a timeout in my Firebase logs.

I’m using:

```
await admin.dbRef.once(‘value’)
.then(snap => {
console.log(snap.exists()) // not logging out
})
```

There is definitely data at my dbRef, and the data is just a few nodes, nothing huge.

I haven’t modified the default timeout behaviour, so I’m guessing the promise of a snapshot is taking over a minute to resolve.

I’m puzzled why this should suddenly happen when I haven’t modified anything likely to affect this snapshot check. Hmm??

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: Can you show how you define `dbRef` as well as the entire code of this Cloud Function?

Comment: Yes, sorry that wasn’t clear: admin.database().ref(‘users/node’) is the full definition. I’m calling.once() on that ref. Like I say, it’s been working fine until now.

Comment: It would be good to see the entire code of this Cloud Function, in particular to check that you return a promise.

Comment: Ah, thanks Renaud! You were right, I did miss the return. It was actually in another method being called within the .then() function. These promise chains often catch me out ;). Thanks for the help!